# OpenCV install with MacPorts, already have python2.7 installed but cannot 'import cv'

Tags: python, opencv, macports

Just get started with my `opencv` project and trying to install `opencv` on my mac. What i have right now is my macport will show:

```
 opencv @3.0.0_1+python27 (active)
```

but i couldn't do import `cv` when i run python in the terminal. Currently i have also installed pycharm, which seems like it comes with `python2.6`, will this be a problem?

Any help will be much appreciate, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With macports, you need to set the default system python.  The issue may be that you are still using the Apple default python.  To check, first run

```
$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
```

That should inform you about which python.  If your python is in /usr/bin, then it could be invalid.

Next, configure the default python to the 2.7 version where you installed OpenCV for.

```
$ sudo port select --summary
Password:
Name        Selected       Options
====        ========       =======
python      python27       python26-apple python27 python27-apple        
python2     python27       python27 none
python3     none           python34 none
```

To set the python version

```
sudo port select --set python python27
```

Just because Apple gives you python2.7, does not mean that the MacPorts libraries are going to link to it.  The nice part with the MacPort version is that they have all of that worked out.

As far as pycharm is concerned, you may not need to set the default python in the console.  Pycharm can link directly to it.  Just go to the project settings, and configure the interpreter to /opt/local/bin/python2.7.

Comment: Really appreciate the help! this is like the very last step i need, and now seems like now i am good to go. So i do figured out there are multiple editions of python on my mac, will that be a problem later on? seems like i have 2.6, 2.7 and apple python(which is 2.7 i believe).